# Techniques to extract artist and song title from a sentence?

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, csv

For context, what I'm trying to do is make a small webapp in which you can paste a Reddit discussion thread, and have song names referenced in the thread converted into a Spotify playlist.

I'm trying to figure out a way to extract artists/song names from some natural language, in the format of of "`artist - song name`" or "`songname by artist`" .

So, for example, say I had the following strings:

```
The Funeral by the Band of Horses is my favorite song.

you should check out the Acoustic version of Foo Fighters - Everlong.

Eminem- Stan. Not a fan of rap but I like this song.
```

the resulting output would be:

```
["The Funeral", "the Band of Horses"],
["Foo Fighters", "Everlong"],
["Eminem", "Stan"]
```

Since there's no way to know what is an artist vs. what is a song without an API call, they don't need to be stored in any particular manner, I just need the artist and song name broken into different array parts.

Is this possible to do without any sort of delimiter to indicate the end of a song name?

Here's what I have so far... (semi-pseudo-code):

```
delimiters = [" - ", "-", " by ",];
strings = [
    "The Funeral by the Band of Horses is my favorite song.",
    "you should check out the Acoustic version of Foo Fighters - Everlong.",
    "Eminem- Stan. Not a fan of rap but I like this song."
];
// loop over each string
for (var i=0; i<strings.length; i++ ) {
    // loop through each delimiter possibility
    for (var d=0; d<delimiters.length; d++) {
        if ( strings[i].indexOf(delimiters[d]) > -1 ) {
            // we have a delimiter match
            // now figure out how to get the stuff on either side...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this is being voted to close as too broad -- I'm asking a very specific question, how to parse a value out of a string with a couple different possible formattings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an interesting library for text parsing: [Knwl.js](https://github.com/loadfive/Knwl.js). Knwl.js doesn't seem to have a plugin for parsing artists or songs, but it seems it should be easy to implement. See: [plugin development](https://github.com/loadfive/Knwl.js/blob/master/plugin_development.md)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are working with natural language, how do you tell Band/Artistname apart from other mentions of the same word.

There can be zillions of ways to build a sentence and you would have to catch all possible.

The other way would be to check your string wordwise and multi-word-wise against a database, that stores names of artists and bands.

Otherwise you will certainly miss some names in the text.